# Why does GNU make always re-link my project?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have the following Makefile in a directory full of `.cpp` and `.h` files:

```
CFLAGS=-g -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -O0
CXX=g++
LDFLAGS=-lgmp -lmathsat -lz3

all: Foo.o Bar.o
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o myexe Foo.o Bar.o $(LDFLAGS)

depend: .depend

.depend: $(wildcard *.cpp)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ > ./.depend

include .depend

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c

clean:
        rm -f *.o myexe
```

When I hit `make`, it invariably executes the last step (linking) even when none of the `.o` files have changed. How can I prevent `make` from doing that? I'd expect `make` to output `Everything up-to-date` or something similar.

I'm on a i686 GNU/Linux machine with GNU Make 3.82 and g++ version 4.8.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make relinks your project because it tries to build `all`. The rule for `all` does not create any file named `all`. Instead it produces `myexe`. Next time you run make, it will see that there's no `all`, but there's a rule to build one, so it dutifully executes that rule which happens to link `myexe` every time you run make.

In order to fix your problem you need to change your makefile to look roughly like this:

```
all: myexe
    echo Build done

myexe: <myexe dependencies go here>
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o myexe $(wildcard *.o) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: May I ask why the edit was rejected? I proposed this in order to sync with the question, which is now edited not to refer to `$(wildcard *.o)` but to `Foo.o Bar.o`. The answer now looks as if Mr. ArtemB had suggested to use `$(wildcard *.o)`. I edited my question in order not to give people bad ideas, because the wildcard thing generally is.

Comment: @Hinton Sorry, I have no idea about edit rejection. In any case they key was to make sure that make rule produce the file that matches the rule. Whether your myexe has wildcard or explicit .o files is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Not at all, it was a comment for the reviewer. You could try to redo the edit yourself and replace `$(wildcard *.o)` with `Foo.o Bar.o`, because the wildcard thing only works when the .o files already exist.

Comment: You should also mark 'all' as a phony target ( add a line: `.PHONY: all` ), seeing as a file called all is not generated from the rule.

Comment: You are correct, though as long as nobody creates the file `all` the rule should work fine as is.

Answer (score 4):

Make always tries to build the top rule. For you, this is `all`. Since your `all` rule doesn't actually make an `all` file it will always be run.

Your probably want your `all` rule to be a `myexe` rule and, if you want an explicit `all` rule, have a dependency only rule: `all: myexe`.

(With GNU Make, you might want to explicitly declare those targets which aren't supposed to generate a real file with a `.PHONY` rule. e.g. `.PHONY: all depend clean`.)

Comment: Too bad I can't accept two answers. ArtemB gave a code sample, so I accepted his one.

Answer (score 3):

`make` is a rule-based expert system.

You give it a heap of rules and a target (default target is the first one listed), and then it builds a complete dependency tree.
All parts are rebuilt iff they are non-existent resp. older than their dependencies, recursively.

The rule you are stumbling over is this: Because the target `all` does not create an output file `all`, make invokes the non-existent-or-outdated rule.

You can correct this by making the target `all` not do any work but instead just depend on the output file. Marking it `.PHONY` is also a good idea.